# Responsive ordering of sidebar elements in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying for a Bootstrap 3 layout with multiple blocks of content in a 75/25% layout.

The problem I'm facing is on a mobile device I need the the first few elements in the right column to come before the body content, and the last few after.

Desktop layout:

```
|------------------|------|
|                  |  r1  |
|      body 1      |------|
|                  |  r2  |
|                  |------|
|------------------|  r3  |
|      body 2      |------|
|                  |  r4  |
|------------------|------|
```

Mobile layout:

```
|---------|
|   r1    |
|---------|
|   r2    |
|---------|
|  body1  |
|---------|
|  body2  |
|---------|
|   r3    |
|---------|
|   r4    |
|---------|
```

A caveat is that the number of sections is not fixed as they can be added/removed by content admins through the CMS.

Normally I would just wrap them in Divs and float the sidebar elements to the right, but is that the right/only way to do it in Bootstrap?

Comment: you can use the `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` classes to show/hide content. Perhaps for something this variable it would be better to have the DOM elements repeated but only visible at certain screen sizes

Comment: To be honest: If you know how to do it without Bootstrap, then don't use Bootstrap.

Comment: Loading the elements multiple times is just not something I'd do... I would have liked to do this in a way that conforms to Bootstrap's basic column model to keep things consistent, but I guess @RoToRa might be right here. Thanks for the input.